# Socket connection and ActorSystem

Tags: sockets, scala, connection, akka

I have an application, that uses akka and now I want to connect to it via a socket connection. Therefor I use a machanism similar to [the one from the scala page](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/55).
But if I try to `tell`, while I have an open `OutputStream`, no message is received by the target.

Here is my source code:

```
object Connector {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val port = 1337
    val conf = ConfigFactory.load
    val system = ActorSystem("SDDB", conf.getConfig("SDDB"))
    val master = system.actorOf(Props[TestActor])
    master ! "a"

    try {
      val listener = new ServerSocket(port)
      println("listening on port: " + port)
      while (true)
        new ConnectionThread(listener accept, master).start
      listener close
    } catch {
      case e: IOException =>
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: " + port + ".")
        System.exit(-1)
    } finally {
      system.shutdown
    }
  }
}

case class ConnectionThread(socket: Socket, master: ActorRef) 
  extends Thread("ConnectionThread") {

  private val Select_* = """select (\w+) from (\w+) on (\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)""".r
  private implicit var id = 0L
  private implicit val timeout = Timeout(25.0 seconds)

  master ! "b"

  override def run {
    master ! "c"
    try{
      master ! "d"
      val in = new ObjectInputStream(socket getInputStream)
      master ! "e"
      val out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket getOutputStream)

      out writeObject("listening")
      out flush

      master ! "f"
      val command = in.readObject.asInstanceOf[String]
      println("client sent: '" + command + "'")
      // process the command

      master ! "g"
      out.writeObject("EOF")
      out.flush

      out.close
      in.close
      socket.close
    } catch {
      case e: SocketException =>
      case e: IOException => e printStackTrace
    }
  }
}

class TestActor extends Actor with ActorLogging{

  log info("TestActor running")

  def receive = {
    case s: String =>
      log info("received: " + s)
  }

}
```

I get the output:

```
listening on port: 1337
[INFO] TestActor running
[INFO] received: a
[INFO] received: b
[INFO] received: c
[INFO] received: d
```

Now I expected it to go on until g, but instead I get:

```
client sent: 'select content from testdata on 2012-07-06'
```

I figured out that it works until I open a Stream of the socket, probably because `tell` and `ask` are socketbased as well and use the outputstream of the socket, the tread runs in. Afterwards the socket connection works, but I am not able to send *any* message to the actor-system.

There is no way for me to drop the Connector and the ConnectionThread. How can I fix it?

Comment: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/scala/io.html

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Unfortunately I can not derive the changes in my code from the documentation. Could you please give me a hint how to change it?

Comment: I can answer specific questions, but I do not have time to program the solution for you.

Comment: I only wanted a hint where I need to include the IOManager.

Comment: If you read the IO docs that I linked to, you see in the end an example of an HttpServer, that should be a place to start.

Comment: Is there an even simpler example?

Comment: Not in the docs, but you can search the akka-user mailing list archive for discussions/questions on that.

Comment: I tried several hours to understand and reimlement the example, bur I can find 'OKResponse' nowhere. Which package did I miss to import?

Comment: OKResponse seems indeed to be missing in the html example, I'll add that. Here's a link to the full code: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-docs/scala/code/docs/io/HTTPServer.scala

Comment: Thank you, now it works. But I would appreciate if there was more inline explanaition. That would make it easier to understand.

Comment: We gladly accept offers to improve the docs, let me know if you are interested in submitting clarifications!

Comment: I think I would, but I did not understand it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must admit, that I did not completly understood the example from the documentation. But I figured out that using a `ConnectionHelper` instead of directly addressing the `ActorRef` works pretty good.

I changed my code to the following:

```
object Connector {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val port = 1337
    val conf = ConfigFactory.load
    val system = ActorSystem("SDDB", conf.getConfig("SDDB"))

    //    val master = system.actorOf(Props[TestActor], "master")
    //    master ! "a"

    try {
      val listener = new ServerSocket(port)
      println("listening on port: " + port)
      while (true)
      //        new ConnectionThread(listener accept, master.asInstanceOf[TestActor]).start
        new ConnectionThread(listener accept, system).start
      listener close
    } catch {
      case e: IOException =>
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: " + port + ".")
        System.exit(-1)
    } finally {
      //      master ! PoisonPill
      system.shutdown
    }
  }

}

case class ConnectionThread(socket: Socket, sys: ActorSystem) 
  extends Thread("ConnectionThread") {

  private val Select_* = """select (\w+) from (\w+) on (\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)""".r
  private implicit var id = 0L
  private implicit val timeout = Timeout(25.0 seconds)
  private val conHelper = new ConnectionHelper

  override def run {
    try {
      val out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket getOutputStream)
      val in = new ObjectInputStream(socket getInputStream)

      conHelper tell "funzt"
      out writeObject ("Hi")
      out.flush
      val command = in.readObject.asInstanceOf[String]
      println("received: " + command)
      out writeObject ("test")
      out.flush
      out writeObject ("EOF")
      out.flush

      out.close
      in.close
      socket.close
    }
  }

  private class ConnectionHelper {
    val tester = sys.actorOf(Props[TestActor])

    def tell(s: String) { tester ! s }

  }

}
```

I don't really understand why this works and the code from my question does not. I welcome all explanations.