# How is the behaviour of this Actor?

Tags: scala, io, actor, akka

I am trying to understand the IO provided by akka. I started another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412790/socket-connection-and-actorsystem) for this issue.

I found a [simple example](http://cognitiveentity.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/simpler-akka-io-example/) on how to use akka IO. I reimplemented it and started it. Now I am wondering why only the first message of the session is printed. 
Can somebody please explain what `state(socket)(Chunk(bytes))` is doing and how I could sent a message to another `Actor` of the `ActorSystem` instead?

**Edit**

I figured out, that the actor just takes a single input and process it by just printing it to the console. That leads me to another question: How can I make the actor take multiple inputs and process them? I connected to the server via putty and if I hit enter one time it processes the input as expected, but if I send another line of input it only stores the input. Where do I have to run `flatMap`, so it processes the next line of input? I tried it inside of the `Read(socket, bytes)` case, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The example you are trying to understand is a bit more advanced, mainly because it is dealing with socket based communication. If you are actually interested in that kind of stuff, I suggest you read [the documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/io.html) where the example from the blog seems to originate from.

In any case, before you do that, a good read would be [Getting Started Tutorial](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/intro/getting-started-first-scala.html) which explains the fundamentals of Akka actors and gives you some actors to play with.

Comment: I already read the example in the documentation, but they are very poor commented. I thought it might be better to find a simpler example. I do understand the way akka deals with actors. My goal is to realize the communication with my actor-system via sockets and all my tries failed.